# Hiding some attributes i.e. textboxes, labels in parent form

Tags: mdi

m using a MDI child form and want it to display when a button from its parent form is clicked, at the same time i want that when the child form appears it should be placed such that some of the attributes of the parent form i.e. picture box is shown while others as labels and textboxes are hidden. Is this possible and how?

Comment: It should be possible, but without more facts it's hard to give any advice. What language and which UI framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language or framework you are using. And I don't get what you mean position so some attributes are hidden.

What I do know is that you should easily be able to hide those objects when you click the button, in C# for example myLabel.Visible = false; or you can use myLabel.Hide() and .Show()

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't worked. My problem is that I'm developing an interface in which a fingerprint would be saved in DB. In the main form the user has enetered his fingerprint (in a picture Box) i want to keep that picture box on the parent form when the save button is clicked and the child form appears.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the controls, which should be always visible on a separate form and make it top-most, so that it always stays on top of every other form.

See this for an example: [How to make a window stay on top](http://www.reviewmylife.co.uk/blog/2008/05/18/c-how-to-make-a-window-stay-on-top-and-become-transparent/)

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm looking for other methods as well. hope to get succussful..